# Where are javascript's regular expressions (regex) used?

Tags: javascript, regex

Are they useful to know? How are they used?

Comment: They are used like in any language, to parse regular structures... It's hard to give any more specific info

Comment: what is your grand overall strategy here? Are you collecting answers to a particular list of off-beat Javascript questions -- answers that'll allow you eventually to take over the entire world?

Comment: @Pointy: You may be [on to something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(technothriller_series\)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are not a JavaScript-specific feature and are typically used to check for faults in use input, for example to notify users who forget the @ or domain part of an email address or too few/many digits in a phone number. For more examples, [look over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+regex).

Answer (score 2):

- [Email address validation](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/email-address-validation.html)

Comment: True, though this also should server as a cautionary example.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is like Perl, has native regular expression notation.
Regular expressions are used to match texts. For example, validating age:

```
if (field.value.match(/^\s*\d+\s*$/) === null) alert("error: invalid age.");
```

Read this for a documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

and JS form validation tutorial:
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Form-Validation-with-JavaScript-Regular-Expressions-Part-1/

Comment: This may be an off-question: are JavaScript regex's considered slow/inefficient?  I mean being that JS is not a compiled language it is easy to write bad regex's that will hog significant resources.