# Having characters outside the end '/' of a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var myRe = /d(b+)d/g;  
var myArray = myRe.exec("cdbbdbsbz");
```

what does that g after the regex do?

Comment: You seem to be asking a series seemingly random, basic questions. I guess that's fine if no one else cares, but I've got to ask why this is. Have you made any attempt to find the answers yourself? I think you'll learn more if you dig in and do a little research yourself instead of having every random curiosity spoon-fed to you.

Comment: @patrick dw: I'm attempting to follow MDN's JavaScript tutorial :D

Comment: OK, I certainly don't mean to offend, but for example, in one of the [recent regex questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541510/where-are-javascripts-regular-expressions-regex-used) you asked, [you were given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541510/where-are-javascripts-regular-expressions-regex-used/4541545#4541545) this [documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which clearly shows what `g` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means ['apply regex globally'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) (or repeatedly) to the target.  It affects replace operations rather than the match expression per se.

Answer (score 1):

The "g" enables global matching and is useful primarily when doing a `replace()` operation. References:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
- http://www.evolt.org/node/36435
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, /g tells the regex engine to search the entire string for occurences, and not stop at the first occurence.

Comment: Very true, but not automatically relevant to Javascript, which the question explicitly tags.  You will earn more reputation if you tune your answer to the question more carefully.